# Why isn't the "axios.post("/api/payment_intents", method able to locate my payment intents?

Tags: reactjs, axios, stripe-payments, http-status-code-404

My goal is to process a test payment using Stripe in a React JS web app. When I enter the test card information, I receive a 404 Error with the following message: "POST /api/payment_intents 404 (Not Found)". Why isn't the "axios.post("/api/payment_intents", method able to locate my payment intents?

[https://github.com/ChicagoJoe1991/saas-template][1]

```
import Stripe from "stripe";

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY);

export default async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const { amount } = req.body;
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount,
        currency: "usd",
      });

      res.status(200).send(paymentIntent.client_secret);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, message: err.message });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
    res.status(405).end("Method Not Allowed");
  }
};


try {
  const { data: clientSecret } = await axios.post("/api/payment_intents", {
    amount: price * 100,
  });

  const paymentMethodReq = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
    type: "card",
    card: cardElement,
    billing_details: billingDetails,
  });

  if (paymentMethodReq.error) {
    setCheckoutError(paymentMethodReq.error.message);
    setProcessingTo(false);
    return;
  }

  const { error } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
    payment_method: paymentMethodReq.paymentMethod.id,
  });

  if (error) {
    setCheckoutError(error.message);
    setProcessingTo(false);
    return;
  }

  onSuccessfulCheckout();
} catch (err) {
  setCheckoutError(err.message);
}
```

};

Comment: have you set the correct axios baseURL? Also make the POST request directly using cURL to verify if the route is exposed properly.

Answer (score 0):

you are not setting `baseURL`.

```
{ axios.post("/api/payment_intents", }
```

You must add some server path like localhost or wherever you are hosting API.